# OpsCenter Commitlog retention policy ignored

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I´m currently working on backing up the commitlogs in cassandra using the "Commitlog Backup" feature in OpsCenter Backups Service.

This project is just in test so we only have a simple cluster with 4 nodes in it.

The problem I´m encountering is that it seems that the retention policy is being ignored on the commitlogs that are being backed up.

I've followed datastax User Guide for enabling commitlog backups (https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/5.2/opsc/online_help/services/opscCommitlogBackups.html)

I've followed these instructions, enabled it in OpsCenter, created a folder on each node were the backups are going in and since this is still in test we did not select any cloud service for the backups to be in.

I put the retention policy on the server for only 5 minutes, but looking at the folder and files on each node the commitlogs that are older than the time set in retention policy won't get deleted.

Permission issues came to my mind but if they are being written then they should have permission to delete them, right?

Anyway we are using OpsCenter 5.2.4 and DataStax Enterprise 4.8.8

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: OpsCenter will not actually delete those files until the next successful archiving, despite the retention time.

Comment: @tom.alexander sorry for asking, what do you mean with next sucessful archiving? Next time the commitlogs gets backed up?

Comment: Yes. The next time commitlogs get backed up, commitlogs older than five minutes should be deleted.

Comment: @tom.alexander okay, even with succesful archiving, the commitlogs that are older than 5 min are not getting deleted.

Comment: Thank you Olafur. I will create an internal ticket for us to investigate.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are on OpsCenter 5.2.4?

Comment: @tom.alexander yes, can confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is finally been solved with a great help from DataStax Support!

The thing is that we are using [Rudder](http://www.rudder-project.org/site/) to keep track of all of the configuration, yaml, conf etc. files on each node to ensure consistency of the files on each node. All file changes that are done need to be done in Rudder because it forces its version of the files on to each node. So if you change f.x. the address.yaml file on one node, Rudder will see that it does not match its version that Rudder has and updates the file to its file contents.

The problem with this is files like [cluster.conf](https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/5.1/opsc/configure/opscConnectionConfig_r.html), that OpsCenter uses, can not be in Rudder because OpsCenter does edit this file regularly and then you don't want Rudder to overwrite OpsCenter changes.

That was the case in our problem. We had the cluster.conf file in Rudder, while OpsCenter did the right thing, editing the cluster.conf file and setting where the Commitlog backup folder was, Rudder kept changing it back to its version which didn't have the commitlog backup folder in it.

The line that OpsCenter was trying to add to the cluster.conf file was:

```
[agents] 
backup_staging_dir = /location/of/your/commitlog/backup/folder
```

We needed to disable this file from Rudder so Rudder wouldn't keep overwriting the cluster.conf file.
Then we could either add this line directly to your cluster.conf file (if the commitlog backup was already turned on) on the OpsCenter node or just start your Commitlog backup again through OpsCenter and let OpsCenter add this line to the cluster.conf file like it should do.